# Probability of 4 consecutive numbers on a random Lotto Max Quick Pick

Tags: probability

Picked up a quick pick Lotto Max ticket from a store today.

The numbers were as follows

14 15 16 17 29 46 47 Quick Pick

It is standard lottery game 7 balls, each number from 1 to 50

What are the odds of getting 4 consecutive numbers on a random quick pick?

Comment: What have you tired?

Answer (score 1):

To cover all the cases, you'll need to either use something like the *inclusion-exclusion principle* or explicitly (and individually) count all the cases with a run of exactly four, a run of exactly five, etc.  Fortunately, since you're asking for four (or more) out of seven, you never have to consider the cases with multiple runs matching within one ticket, so these are all mutually exclusive and cover all the possibilities. I'll work the cases with a run of exactly four so you can see how it works:

We'll start similarly to wjmccann's answer, by looking at where the run of four can begin and where the other numbers can be chosen from.  In principle, the run of four can begin at any of 47 different positions (1..4 through 47..50), and since there are six numbers that can't be chosen (the run itself, and either of the two numbers adjacent to it), for each run of four the remaining three numbers can be chosen from any of the 50-6=44 other places, and so the count of tickets is 'roughly' $47\cdot {44\choose 3}$.  Unfortunately, there's a small catch in this due to edge effects; for two of those 47 cases (the (1..4) case and the (47..50) case), we can actually choose the remaining three numbers from *45* different places rather than 44.  So the precise count of tickets with a run of *exactly* four numbers in them is $2\cdot{45\choose 3}+(47-2)\cdot{44\choose 3}$.  You should be able to find the precise counts of tickets with runs of exactly five numbers, exactly six numbers, and exactly seven numbers in them; adding these then gives the total count of tickets with a run of (at least) four consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with tickets that have *at least* four consecutive numbers, than this isn't that tough.

First we choose a starting number for our sequence of four consecutive numbers. In the numbers $1-50$ we have $47$ possible sequences for this. Now we need to select the remaining three numbers for your ticket from the other $46$ possible numbers. Finally, to get the probability you multiply these together and then divide by all possible tickets.

$$
\dfrac{47\binom{46}{3}}{\binom{50}{7}} \approx .714\%
$$

Comment: This multiply counts some cases; for instance, you might choose 12 as the starting point for the sequence of four and 11 as one of the other 3 numbers, or choose 11 as the starting point for the sequence of four and 16 as one of the other three numbers.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said *at least* four consecutive numbers, since this includes the possibility of a sequence of $5,6,7$. I didn't think it mattered since the original question doesn't specify that it must be a sequence of $4$

Comment: The problem is that this counts those sequences of 5+ more than once; your answer will generate e.g. the set of numbers $\{11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 22, 25\}$ in multiple separate ways, but that set should only be counted once.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, each separate instance is an individual ticket that includes a sequence of at least $4$ numbers. The sequence itself is not unique per ticket, however it increases the probability of finding a sequence of $4$.

Comment: My point is that your value $47{46\choose 3}$ doesn't represent the number of different _tickets_ that include sequences of at least four numbers, because you count some tickets (like the one above) multiple times.  Consider a simpler case, where there are four numbers chosen out of 6, and you want the number of tickets with at least 3 numbers consecutive; your answer would suggest that there are four starting points (1/2/3/4) for the sequence of three numbers and that the last number can be chosen from the remaining three numbers in $3\choose 1$ ways, for a total of 12 possible tickets.

Comment: But in fact, there are only 9: $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $\{1, 2, 3, 5\}$, $\{1, 2, 3, 6\}$, $\{1, 3, 4, 5\}$, $\{1, 4, 5, 6\}$, $\{2, 3, 4, 5\}$, $\{2, 3, 4, 6\}$, $\{2, 4, 5, 6\}$, and $\{3, 4, 5, 6\}$. The discrepancy is because the formula $4\cdot{3\choose 1}$ counts sequences like $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ twice.

Comment: Oh crap I see what you mean. So I should subtract off larger sequences then?

Comment: That's one way: _inclusion-exclusion_. But that can get tricky too. My preferred means for something like this would be to separately count the number of tickets with a sequence of _exactly_ four, a sequence of _exactly_ five, a sequence of _exactly_ six, and a sequence of _exactly_ seven; there are some slightly tricky edge conditions to be considered but each of these is relatively straightforward to count. I'll see if I can turn this into a proper answer.